# COMO INCRUSTAR UN VIDEO DE YOUTUBE EN EL CUERPO DEL MENSAJE DE OUTLOOK

Tags: outlook

Hola que tal espero me puedan ayudar
quiero incrustar un video de youtube en el cuerpo del mensaje de outlook pero que al mismo tiempo se pueda reproducir en miniatura sin necesidad de que te redirija a otra pagina

actualmente tengo este codigo creado con la plataforma de videomail pero al cambiar la ruta del video ya no lo muestra en el cuerpo del mensaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al adjuntar el archivo.html en el cuerpo del mensaje outlook no lo puede leer intente con todas las opciones y no lo he logrado

[image: mensaje de outlook al agregar el archivo]

Comment: Hola bienvenido a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Edita la pregunta y agrega el código como texto en lugar de una imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con un iframe en la estructura de tu plantilla de mail.

Código:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YI6AtpWQM3k?modestbranding=1&amp;playsinline=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1"
              allowfullscreen
              allowtransparency
              allow="autoplay"
              ></iframe>
```

Comment: ya lo realize pero me aparecen las opciones que publique con ninguna lo puede leer

Comment: Para poder entender lo que tratas de hacer tiene que compartir un poco mas de información.

Comment: mi forma de ingresar el codigo a outlook es creando una nueva pestaña para poder adjuntar el codigo pero es ahi donde me dice que no puede leer el codigo